# ADODB Prepare Statement in PHP Throwing Error

Tags: php, oracle, prepared-statement, adodb

We have PHP 5.2.13 and ADODB version 2.8 for our website using Oracle database. Initially, we had queries that were not parameterized and could invite SQL injection. So, we decided to switch to parameterized queries. Now, when I try to "prepare" the statement, I get the error of "***Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another***". I have tried all possible codes available but no luck. Could it be that ADODB 2.8 doesn't support prepared statements? Strange thing is that if I write the function name wrong like prepar (without E), I still get above mentioned error.

Sample code that I am using is given below:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT NAME, POSITION FROM DEPT WHERE NAME=? AND DEPT=?");
```

I have also tried binding parameters using colon but no luck. There is a lot of code for OCI and MYSQL available but Oracle seems like a grey area to the people using PHP.

PS: I don't know much about PHP as it's not my area of expertise.

Comment: You are using the same placeholder two times, the `?`. I guess the `prepare()` statement doesn't accept two equal placeholders.

Comment: Even if I use one, error will be same.

Comment: Can you run the query if you do it manually, e.g. copy&paste it into the SQL Console and replace the `?` with actual values?

Comment: Yes, query works perfectly. Error is thrown for every query even if it's like SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL

Comment: Try to write only the keyword uppercase, maybe this is an issue.

Comment: That didn't work either. I believe ADODB 2.8 doesn't support prepared statements. I have Googled to check the kind of functions it supports but of no use. I downloaded ADODB 5.20.9 and found that it has support for prepared statements. But I don't know how to check this in the installed version (I can't simply replace older version with new one like that as it's live system).

Comment: @TobiasF. `?` is a fairly standard positional place-holder and that's how it's meant to be.